# Is UILabel the best way to display a simple vertical bar graph in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I need to display several vertical bar graphs, side by side, on an iPhone.
The graphs may be different, simple colors (red, green, yellow).
The length of each graph may vary.
I'll be updating no more often than once a second.

I'm planning to use `UILabel` for each bar graph, because that's the way I did it as an iOS newbie several years ago.  It was simple and looked great.

Is there a faster/better way in iOS?
Perhaps using animation tools?

Comment: can you try UUchart library to achieve graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't see what a bar graph has to do with UILabel at all. I'd use rectangular layers or views (either of which could easily be animated as the graph changes), or even just draw the bar graph in code.

Comment: CALayer looks best for me.  So, my plan is to create 1st layer to contain all the vertical bar graphs; create sublayer for each bar graph; create a smaller sublayer, within each bar graph sublayer, that is s different color that represents aberration from the 1st bar graph's value.

Comment: And layers are animatable with CABasicAnimation and similar, so you can have a lot of fun with this as the values change.